# Macbook moves windows on single click

Tags: macos, window-manager, touchpad

On occasion, when I click on a window (by tapping on the trackpad), the window goes into some strange movement mode - keyboard input is ignored, and wherever I click next the window is moved to (and strange mode reverted).

I can't find anything in preferences that relates to this.  I'd rather have it turned off completely, but I'd settle for knowing how I'm accidentally doing it, so I can avoid doing so.

This is on 10.6.8.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the *Drag Lock* option in the *Trackpad* section of System Preferences. Try disabling that setting and see if the issue goes away.

Comment: See, I thought that sounded reasonable, too.  But Drag Lock is not only not checked, it's greyed out - it only is enable-able if one-finger dragging is enabled, which it isn't.  I have tried in the past enabling and disabling it to see if that would fix it - no luck.